# Conditional probability. Is it correct solution?

Tags: probability

"Each natural number, independently of the others, is a trap with a probability of 0.4.
Regardless of this, the hare jumps on natural numbers starting at 1 and jumping to the right by 0,1 or 2 with probability 1/3 per unit of time regardless of the values ​​of past jumps. Prove that the hare will fall into the trap with probability 1. "

Solution: Let if the hare fall into a trap,  it continues to jump, then with probability one it will visit an infinite number of points. Let the sequence of points a1, a2 ... an ... be the hare's path, then the conditional probability that the hare will not fall into the trap (provided that its path a1, a2, ...) is equal to the probability that in none of these points (ai) there is no trap and is equal to 0.4 to infinity and is equal to 0. Is this enough to conclude that the probability of falling into a trap is 0? Can this decision be made more formal?

Comment: This is not clear.    Are you talking about infinite time?   If so...well, with probability $1$ there are two consecutive traps somewhere down the line and  the hare is certain to land in one of those eventually (unless he's been trapped previously).

Answer (score 1):

Formal proof: Let $X_n$ denote the $n$th new natural number occupied by the hare, assuming (as you suggested to do, and this is a good idea) that the hare jumps forever, even after having met a trap.

Let $A_n$ denote the event that the hare has met no trap after having visited $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, then $$P(A_n\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)=(0.6)^n$$ hence $$P(A_n)=(0.6)^n\to0\tag{1}$$ Now, the event $A$ that the hare never meets any trap is $$A=\bigcap_nA_n$$ hence, for every $n$, $$P(A)\leqslant P(A_n)\tag{2}$$ Assertions $(1)$ and $(2)$ together imply that $P(A)=0$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that the hare is trapped if starts at $n.$  We may suppose the hare starts at $1.$  Then $$p_1 = .4 +.6\left(\frac{p_1}{3}+\frac{p_2}{3}+\frac{p_2}{3}\right),$$ for with probability $.4, 1$ is a trap, and with probability $.6, 1$ is not a trap, and the hare jumps to $1,2,\text{ or }3$ with equal probabilities.  By symmetry, $p_n$ is the same for every natural number $n,$ so the equation is $$p=.4+.6p\implies p=1.$$